# How to stop .swp files being generated?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am unable delete .swp files present in my directory.I am not able to stage those files also. How to stop those files from being generated and what is the reason for these .swp files appeared in my folder?

[image]

Comment: Can we get a bit more context, please? You *should* be able to push to the remote git repo, regardless of any un-staged files. You *should* be able to stage those files, also (but that's almost certainly not what you want to do!). And you *should* be able to delete those files just like any other file on your computer! So, can we see exactly what tools you're using/commands you're running/etc?

Comment: Sorry i am able to push to code to git repository. but how to delete the .swp files ?

Comment: How do you delete any other file on your computer? `rm filename`? Right click it, then select "delete"? If you're asking *"How to stop those files from being generated in the first place?"* then that's a valid question, but I honestly don't understand why you're asking "how to delete a file"?!?!

Comment: Okay could you please tell me how to stop those files from being generated??

Comment: Does [the first result on google](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/177/what-is-the-purpose-of-swap-files) answer your question? If not, then please create a new question explaining **what you've tried and researched**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` file and put:

```
*.swp
```

If you want to really delete all .swp files, just `rm *.swp` in the command line terminal, before adding, commiting and pushing.

.swp files are created by Vim, they should be automatically deleted when you close the file and exit the editor.